# How to open a fragment from a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have made a project in which main Activity opens fragment(web.java) and I added a button in (web.java) when it clicked it should open a new fragment(next.java), but when I run app and click on button app close.

MAIN ACTIVITY class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            android.app.FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
            fn.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new web()).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();


        }
    }

    );

}

}
```

WEB class

```
    public class web extends Fragment {

    View v;

     @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_fragment, container, false);

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String pdf_url = "http://mycbseguide.com/";
        mWebView.loadUrl(pdf_url);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


        return v;


    }


     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           android.app.FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
                                           fn.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new next()).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();


                                       }
                                   }

        );
    }
}
```

NEXT class

```
public class next extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_fragment, container, false);

    WebView mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String pdf_url = "http://mycbseguide.com/";
    mWebView.loadUrl(pdf_url);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    return v;


}}
```

LOG

```
08-13 17:33:49.943 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.prashant.webview.next.access$super
08-13 17:33:49.944 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.prashant.webview.next.access$super
08-13 17:33:49.953 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0b0064 (com.example.prashant.webview:id/container) for fragment next{42579268 #0 id=0x7f0b0064}
08-13 17:33:49.954 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
08-13 17:33:49.955 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:   Local FragmentActivity 4232d178 State:
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:     mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:     mLoadersStarted=true
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:   FragmentManager misc state:
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:     mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@4232e088
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@4232e088
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:   View Hierarchy:
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42346278 V.E..... ... 0,0-720,1184}
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:       android.widget.LinearLayout{42347638 V.E..... ... 0,0-720,1184}
08-13 17:33:49.956 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{4234e8c8 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020312}
08-13 17:33:49.957 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:         android.widget.FrameLayout{4234ecf8 V.E..... ... 0,50-720,1184}
08-13 17:33:49.957 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:           android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{42353468 V.ED.... ... 0,0-720,1134 #7f0b0043 app:id/decor_content_parent}
08-13 17:33:49.957 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{423566b8 V.ED.... ... 0,112-720,1134 #1020002 android:id/content}
08-13 17:33:49.957 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:               
08-13 17:33:49.959 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager: android.widget.RelativeLayout{4236d1a8 V.E..... ... 0,0-720,1022 #7f0b0054 app:id/content_frame}
08-13 17:33:49.959 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:                 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{4236dd78 VFED..C. ... 272,463-448,559 #7f0b0055 app:id/button}
08-13 17:33:49.959 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer{42358c68 V.ED.... ... 0,0-720,112 #7f0b0044 app:id/action_bar_container}
08-13 17:33:49.959 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:               android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{423593e0 V.E..... ... 0,0-720,112 #7f0b0045 app:id/action_bar}
08-13 17:33:49.959 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:                 android.widget.TextView{4236a558 V.ED.... ... 32,29-193,83}
08-13 17:33:49.959 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:                 android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView{42384790 V.E..... ... 720,0-720,112}
08-13 17:33:49.959 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/FragmentManager:               android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView{42363178 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0046 app:id/action_context_bar}
08-13 17:33:49.963 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.prashant.webview, PID: 30487
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0064 (com.example.prashant.webview:id/container) for fragment next{42579268 #0 id=0x7f0b0064}
`                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
```

`

```
                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:698)
                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 17:33:49.943 30487-30487/com.example.prashant.webview E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.prashant.webview.next.access$super
```

Comment: What are button1 and button2 for?

Comment: button1 is in mainactivity.class when clicked go to web.class and button2 in web.class when clicked go to next.class

Comment: where is the app stopping?

Comment: when I click on button1

Comment: try using 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager' instead of 'android.app.FragmentManager'.

Comment: trying wish it works

Comment: If that does not work, try replacing 'getFragmentManager()' with 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

Comment: when I use android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager then many methods override  and many error shows

Comment: Ok, go back to what you had. I think the problem is with the web fragment.

Comment: Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                              android.app.FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
                              fn.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new next()).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();


                                       }
                                   }

        ); MOVE THIS CODE FROM ONCREATE TO ONCREATEVIEW

Comment: Now when I click on button2 the app close

Comment: one strange if the Button2 is in activity container why you are not handling it as you did Button1? it is going to same thing which you are trying web..... if its is in web_fragment then you have serious issue onCreate gets call before onCreateView check fragment lifecycle

Comment: I am trying both open web and what do u mean by handling of button1

Comment: can you change onCreate to onViewCreated and test

Comment: onViewCreated  this method is now show when I click ctrl+o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a fragment, you should use views inside onCreateView and not inside onCreate as you'd do on an Activity. So, in the web fragment, what you've done is used the button view inside onCreate(). This is causing the problem.

```
Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       android.app.FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
                                       fn.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new next()).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();


                                   }
                               }

    );
```

So try moving this part of code inside your onCreateView(). Hope this works.

In the Next fragment, you are using the same layout as of the web fragment.
[image]

Replace the R.layout.web_fragment (highlighted red) to a different layout file for the Next fragment.

Comment: Now app close when I click on button2 ( 
button1 is in mainactivity.class when clicked go to web.class and button2 in web.class when clicked go to next.class )

Comment: is container in your web_fragment?

Comment: yes, It is in web_fragment and it is RelativeLayout

Comment: I have posted the log

Comment: copy and paste the log inside the "enter code here" box

Comment: Done checkout the Log and please give me solution

Comment: I changed to web_fragment even now the app close

Comment: you changed to web_fragment? I said replace that with something else. You should be keeping Next Fragment's layout there.

Comment: is content_frame in main activity, too relative layout?

Comment: Try using FrameLayout instead of Relative Layout

Comment: I changed mainactivity relativelayout to Frame layout even now it is not working

Comment: also, change the R.id.container in the web_fragment to FrameLayout

Comment: even not it close on button2  click

Comment: Are you sure R.id.container is inside web_fragment layout?

Comment: i dont have teamViewer

Comment: I do have remote Desktop from chrome

Comment: what is remote desktop

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en

Comment: u have fb id if i post on this it will be public

Comment: my facebook name is Karun Shrestha or, username is kars.kit

Comment: oo it change every time this is 736155575677

Answer (score 1):

Just add `LinearLayout` at bottom of inside main layout like this,

After that just add the fragment like this,

```
android.app.FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
fn.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, new web()).addToBackStack("tag").commit();
```

Comment: where I add linear layout?

Comment: in which class I change the code for opening fragment?

Comment: You can pass this add or replace  fragment  code inside your click event.