# How to open a Fragment from an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have MainActivity that has 3 fragments. In one of the fragments, I have a login feature that redirects to a new Activity. On pressing logout, I need it back to the Fragment it started with (second) and not the first fragment. 
Code referred:
[Get back to a fragment from an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927500/get-back-to-a-fragment-from-an-activity), [How to open a fragment from a fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931907/how-to-open-a-fragment-from-a-fragment)

None of these help.

I have tried this too:

```
 Button Logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                 ft.replace(CurrentClass.this, MainActivity.class);

                }
            });
```

Comment: you have no control of Fragment creation and destruction, so achieving this could be as complicated or easy as you want. The simplest solution is to create a flag in `SharedPreferences` and act upon it on fragments' creation

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call this after `ft.replace()`

```
ft.commit()
```